# dynamically adding conditional validation using jquery validator

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I wanted to add conditional rules dynamically on the page load here is my code what I have tried
I have created [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TYbS5/) 
First code sample

```
 $("input[name$='DistanceToRespondingFireDept']").rules("add", {
        required: {
            depends: function (element) {
                return $("input:radio[name='DistanceToNearestFireHydrnt']:checked").val() == 'U';
            }
        },
        messages: {
            required: "Tested"
        }
    });
```

second code

```
$("input[name$='DistanceToRespondingFireDept']").rules("add", {
        required: function (element) {
            return $("input:radio[name='DistanceToNearestFireHydrnt']:checked").val() == 'U';
        },
        messages: {
            required: "Tested"
        }
    });
```

I get an error "cannot call method call of undefined"

If I don't add any conditions do just simple required: true it works

Any suggestion how to fix

Comment: You don't need `<html>`, `<head>` or `<body>` tags in your jsFiddle; just insert the HTML that's between your `<body></body>`.

Comment: You should also show your full code example in the OP.  Otherwise, when the jsFiddle dies, the question will not be as helpful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error.

The opening brace, `{`, was missing from here...

```
if (test === "a") { // <-- this opening brace was missing
```

**Your DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/TYbS5/4/

You should also update your jQuery Validate plugin to version 1.11.1, which is currently the latest.

And finally, both of your buttons are `type="submit"` which means the plugin will think they're both for submitting the form.  You should change the "CLEAR" button into `type="button"` in order to prevent the plugin from capturing its click event.

---

**EDIT**:

As per comments, here is code for conditional validation...

```
required: function() {
    return $('#DistanceToNearestFireHydrnt1').is(':checked');
},
```

**Working DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/TYbS5/5/

Comment: I had updated the JS fiddle but forgot to update it in the question for { error. Secondly this is a dummy form created for testing So have not changed the button type a simple copy paste :-(

Comment: @diveshsalian, So what's the problem then? Your code is working without error as demonstrated by my jsFiddle.

Comment: I want to add conditional validation not just required:true I have shared the code sample in question i.e required if selected radiobutton value is U